# react-router-dom v4 404 pageNotFound <Route path="*".../> not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have tried several combinations but `<Route path="*" component={PageNotFound}/>` is not landing to `PageNotFound` if any route is hit (that is not declared) but lands to `/` I think.

Is there another way or am I doing something incorrect? Rest of the app seems to run fine though.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

export const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <MainApp>
          <Route path="/list" component={List}/>
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
          <Switch>
            <User path="/user" >
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/user/staticUser" component={UserStatic} />
                <Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserID} />
              </Switch>
            </User>
          </Switch>
        </MainApp>
        <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

More info:

```
/ - Home - parent of all (almost)
/List - inside home
/Settings - inside home
/Login - standalone
/Users - inside home, For now just showing itself. It has further pages.
/User/123 - inside user with /:id
/User/staticUser - inside user with static route
/garbage - not a route defined (not working as expected)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using react-router-dom package (v4)

If you are looking to render a `NoMatchFound` Component when you don't match a specific route in your app, you just need to specify a `<Route>` without a path.

Something like this - `<Route component={NoMatch} />`

Here is an example of my routes in my application.

```

```
  <Router>
    <AppContainer>
      <Route component={Header} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={MDashboard} />

        <Route path="/monitor/:groupId/:tab" component={Monitor} />
        <Route path="/monitor/:groupId" component={Monitor} />
        <Route exact path="/insights" component={IDashboard} />

        <Route component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </AppContainer>
  </Router>
```

```

Comment: Anup, Thanks for replying but A) I do NOT want `/login` to have `Header` nor inside `Container` or `Home`. Its standalone Please let me know what fits my use case. B) I may or many not nest routes for few components and not for others (as shown in example) C) I tried deleting `"*"` but its giving same results

Comment: @Masood I have the same issue. Did you ever figure out how to do a gloabl not found page?